# Recursive or direct forecasting used in forecast/predict() in stats models

Tags: time-series, forecasting, statsmodels

I am working on a time series project. I have an hourly series and I have to forecast the 24 next hours.

I am facing a problem with understanding how both the stats models forecast() and predict() methods work. Because they give me different results, I think are they working differently.

I want to implement a recursive forecasting (e. g. The last value predicted is used to predict the next one step prediction) to perform multi-step out-of-sample forecasts. Do I have to implement it or it is already done by these method ? I haven’t found any explanations and details about it.

I am using the SARIMAX model.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Cross-Validated. Can you share the code you are using and plots of the results? There are different possible reasons for the discrepancy between predict() and forecast() and I won't be able to answer your questions without additional details.

Comment: also add your actual data ....

Comment: Hi guys thanks you for your answer but I cannot post my data but I will give an example and edit my post soon to add details

Comment: why don't you scale your data and post the scaled data OR create a simulated series that reflects your data.

Answer (score 0):

`forecast` gives recursive out-of-sample forecasts. The default for `predict` is to give in-sample fitted values (although it can also do out-of-sample forecasts if you pass it the right arguments).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer it is a bit clearer for me. If I am right : forecast(nsteps=10) method predict the first out-of-sample step and reuse it to predict the second out-of-sample step ? Until the 10th prediction? 
Is it « normal » that this méthode forecast the same pattern for multi step forecasting? 

For predict() methode how do you do both type of forcasts (in-sample and our-of-sample) is it the « dynamic » attribute? How do you use it?

Comment: Yes, you can think of `forecast` as reusing the previous forecasts for the subsequent steps (what it actually does is perform the Kalman filter recursions, but the practical effect is the same).

Comment: I don't know what you meant by "Is it « normal » that this méthode forecast the same pattern for multi step forecasting?". However, the Kalman filter is a widely used method for producing recursive forecasts for SARIMAX-type models.

Comment: The `predict` method is just more general than the `forecast` method, because it accepts `start` and `end` values. If you do `res.predict(start=res.nobs, end=res.nobs + 4)`, this will give the same answer as if you did `res.forecast(steps=5)`. However, if you did `res.predict(start=res.nobs - 1, end=res.nobs + 4)`, then the first returned element would be the in-sample fitted value for the last observation, and the remaining 5 elements would be out-of-sample forecasts.

Comment: You can think of the `dynamic` argument as specifying when the predicted values start to be used to recursively predict the next values (for in-sample predictions), instead of using the actual data to predict the next values.

Comment: Thank you very much, you exactly helped me on points where I was confused about ! Can I ask where did you get these knowledge Kaplan filter recursions? I haven’t seen any informations about this in stats model documentation

Comment: You can take a look at this documentation page https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/statespace.html to see the details about how SARIMAX is related to Kalman filtering